# Ubuntu 12.04 does not detect monitor at boot

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, resolution, monitor

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 for a couple of months now with no problems.  Then one day I restarted my computer, and it would not detect the monitor.  If I force it to restart a few times, it finally gets me to a grub screen where I can only boot in recovery mode, and then it only displays in a v. low resolution.  I don't have multiple monitors.  I'm using a ViewSonic VP2330wb, and have an Intel graphics driver, which I have updated and it still doesn't fix the problem.  I have been using the same monitor since I got the computer, and this has never been a problem.

I would really love to fix this without having to reinstall.

Thanks.

Comment: This is my video card: description: VGA compatible controller product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 version: 09 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources: memory:fe000000-fe3fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with one of my monitors. I would go through some troubleshooting to test a few things:

- Test the monitor on a different computer.
- Plug a different monitor into the same port of the GFX card
- Update the graphics card driver
- Change cables: power and monitor

Unfortunately what I had found was that my monitor was dead. Upon asking others for opinions on a course of action, I was told that it would in fact be much cheaper just to buy a new monitor.

Comment: I unfortunately can't try the monitor on another computer--I only have a v. old mac laptop that doesn't have a proper adapter for a dvi-d cable.  The monitor itself is a few years old, but the dvi cable I'm using to hook it up with is brand new.  What also confuses me is that in the Display settings, it says I'm using a laptop screen.

Comment: So I edited grub and added 'nomodeset' after 'quiet splash', which was something that I had seen recommended in several places.  With that I can at least get Ubuntu to load in 'generic' instead of 'recovery mode', but still it does not always detect the monitor at boot, and the resolution still is not fixed.

Comment: I was finally able to solve this by getting a new VGA cord and using that instead of the DVI cord.  All booting problems were fixed after that.